# Resources(js/css/images) are not working after spring security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

1) I have configured application using pure java configuration. **Everything seems to be working correctly except css/js/images.** The application is available on Github at

https://github.com/rajendersaini/cabms/

Just want to point out the configuration

AppConfig - spring mvc config - register resources using

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
```

and in SecurityConfig -

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(LoginController.AUTHLOGIN,
                        ResourceConfig.RESOURCE_PATH_MATCHER).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin()
                .loginPage(LoginController.AUTHLOGIN);
```

Can you please help fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Where do your static resources end up in your war file? I ask because you have them under the WEB-INF directory. I don't know if Spring will allow you to serve public content out of WEB-INF.

In my build, I have my static stuff under

```
src/main/webapp/resources/...
    /css
    /js
    /img
```

This way, they end up at the top level of the war file under the /resources directory. You could give that a shot.

Comment: Spring allows them from any dir. Till now everything was working fine. When i introduced security everything seems to stopped working. Anyways thanks for looking into it, really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1) Finally my application resources are working - few changes I have made, In my mvc app config, I don't know when I introduced this line and this was the culprit. I will investigate it later

```
   @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
                        DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
                configurer.enable();
        }
```

2) Java webapp initializer was looking for mapping which should be "/*" instead of "/"

3) In headers and footer we need to have context appended to resource paths.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify a secure rule which will ignore an application security for static resources. Try to add code like this in your Spring Security configuration class:

```
       public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
```